# WantReadError is raising while sending apple push notifications

Tags: python, django, openssl, apple-push-notifications, pyopenssl

I'm trying to send apple push notifications with [django-ios-notifications app](https://github.com/stephenmuss/django-ios-notifications), but i've faced with WantReadError. 
Here is a stacktrace:

```
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ios_notifications/models.py", line 110, in push_notification_to_devices
    self._write_message(notification, devices, chunk_size)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ios_notifications/models.py", line 132, in _write_message
    self._connect()
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ios_notifications/models.py", line 100, in _connect
    return super(APNService, self)._connect(self.certificate, self.private_key, self.passphrase)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ios_notifications/models.py", line 64, in _connect
    self.connection.do_handshake()
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1076, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 847, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise WantReadError()
WantReadError
```

I have no idea how to fix it.

I've created required APNService with correct Certificate and Private key, hostname is gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com.

Command like this 
`openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert my.pem` works fine in Ubuntu, it returns

```
Start Time: 1458724825
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

**UPDATE:** problem was solved. 
According to https://github.com/stephenmuss/django-ios-notifications/issues/11 it's required to install https://github.com/mjs/gevent_openssl